# how to pop up the alert when click the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

i am newbie with html and jquery. i want to show an alert box when click the link. but seems the jquery function doesn't work. 
not sure the selector or something else is wrong.

please suggest. thanks.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>text1</p>
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>text3</p>

        <input type=button onClick="location.href='http://www.test.com/?test=123'" value='click here'>

        <div class="modify">
            <a href="http://www.test.com" id="myHref">test1</a>
            <p/>
            <a href="http://www.test.com" id="myHref">test2</a>
            <p/>
            <a href="#" id="myHref1" class="button mini-button blue">test3</a>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ($) {
                alert('test');
            }
            $self.find("#myHref").each(function () {
                $(this).on("click", function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                    alert ($this.attr('href'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have many errors in your JS..Could you please tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated code

```js
function n($) {
    alert('test');
}

n()
$(document).find("#myHref").each(function () {
    $(this).on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        alert ($this.attr('href'));
      return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<html>
<body>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='http://www.test.com/?test=123'" value='click here'>
<div class="modify">
<a href="http://www.test.com" id="myHref">
    test1
</a>
<p/>
<a href="http://www.test.com" id="myHref">
    test2
</a>
<p/>
<a href="#" id="myHref1" class="button mini-button blue">
    test3
</a>
</div>


<body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").on("click",".modify a", function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're referencing `JQuery` in your question you can enjoy the magic using the `click` event directly with your links :

```
$(function(){ //ready function
    $('#myHref').click(function(){ //click event
         alert($(this).attr('href'));
    });
})
```

Hope that this what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onclick in event of href just simple:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<html>
    <body>
        <p>text1</p>
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>text3</p>
        <input type=button onClick="location.href='http://www.test.com/?test=123'" value='click here'>
        <div class="modify">
            <p>
                <a href="http://www.test.com" id="myHref" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">test1</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="http://www.test.com" id="myHref" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">test2</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="http://www.test.com" id="myHref1" class="button mini-button blue" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">test3</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And remember always open and /close tags. eg:

```
<body>
   <div>
       <p>
       </p>
   </div>
</body>
```